# setting up phpMyAdmin with WAMP server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I got phpmyadmin to log on, and followed this [link](http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/08/25/how-to-install-and-setup-apache-mysql-and-php-in-windows/). Now the problem is that I wrote php code for accessing a database and reading data from the tables using a sql query but it fails to find the database I created using mysql command line console. However, it can find the database I created using the phpmyadmin.  Why is that?

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [sf] or possibly [su]

Comment: I think while installing you have setup a root password. Goto your wamp folder in your command prompt and search for the MYSQL.EXE file. Open mysql in command prompt and remove the password from there.. You can type mysql -? for help. :)

Comment: hey Jim, well i was tweaking around with the installations and every thing and got the phpmyadmin to start up, i then wrote some PHP code to access the database i created on mysql command prompt, and it does not show on phpmyadmin and neither does my php code able to access it. However i created a database using phpmyadmin and then my php code was able to access it... could you help me understand why cant my php code access the database created via sql command line console? regards

Answer (score 1):

Several things could be the case here:

- Have you set the blowfish secret?

  ```
  $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '7hfs97fs4fs847';
  ```
- Have you set the auth config parameter?

  ```
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
  ```
- Tried logging in with a blank password?

  ```
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
  ```
- reset the root password for MySQL?

  ```
  mysql>use mysql;
  mysql>update user set Password=PASSWORD('NewPass') where User='root';
  mysql> flush privileges;
  mysql>exit
  ```

Let me know if one of these solution helped you.

Comment: well i tried all but no luck, i created a database with some tables and every thing works on the mysql command line console even the root password that is prompted in the beginning, only when i connect using phpmyadmin, it just wont connect.

Comment: Hi, i figured out the problem... it was using transactions in mysql, i just typed in "commit" after i created all tables and entered data in. Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Read the official documentation, you`ll have to setup some other variables too: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/Documentation.html#setup

For example: 
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';`

Comment: the thing is i installed wamp server and phpmyadmin comes with it as a n app. so when i installed wamp phpmyadmin was installed with it. mysql works well even the password works only phpmyadmin doesnt? i tries changing the config.php file to set the password to my password still nothing...